DevExtream Show popup on datagird row click
I want to show display the pop up (app-process-enrollment) on row click rather than the button click (process column):
I've tried using (onRowClick) on the grid, but cannot get the data to properly load in the popup.
conn-item.component.html
<dx-data-grid *ngIf="sessions && sessions.length > 0" id="sessions" [dataSource]="sessions" keyExpr="Id"
    [columnAutoWidth]="true" [allowColumnResizing]="true" [hoverStateEnabled]="true" [showBorders]="false"
    [showColumnLines]="false" [showRowLines]="true">

    <dxi-column dataField="S.CD" caption="Created" dataType="date" sortOrder="desc"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column *ngIf="c.t== 0" dataField="Summary.pc" caption="PCCost"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column *ngIf="c.t == 0" caption="View" cellTemplate="process"></dxi-column>

    <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'process'">
        <app-en [s]="decaudates"></app-en>
    </div>
</dx-data-grid>

app-en.component.html
<ng-container *ngIf="mode == 'button'">
    <span class="" (click)="showImportUtility()"></span>    
</ng-container>

<!-- full screen enrollment process tool -->
<app-dialog #dialog [toolbarTitle]="screenTitle" [fullScreenOnLoad]="true" [showCloseButton]="true"
    [dragEnabled]="false" [visible]="showTool" (dialogClosed)="onDialogClosed()">
    ...
    ...
</app-dialog>

app-en.component.ts:
showImportUtility(): void {
    this.sId = this.s.ISId;
    this.PSC = this.s.PSC;
    this.showTool = true;
}


You are adding the dialog component inside every row. Instead of doing this, i recommend adding this component only once outside the data-grid. Initially hidden. Use the onRowClick event to set the current row data in a variable and bind it to the dialog component and make it visible.
